# How do you prove there are ceil(n / 2) leaves in a binary heap of n nodes?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-heap

How do you prove that a binary heap with n nodes has exactly ⌈n / 2⌉ leaf nodes?

Answer (score 6):

```
Let x be the height of tree in which case 2^x = no of leaves
=> 2^0 + 2^1+ 2^2 + 2^3 +...2^x = n
=> 2^(x+1) - 1 = n (By sum series power of 2 formula)
=>2^(x+1)= n+1
=> log(n+1) = x+1
=>log(n+1)-1 = x;
=>log(n+1)- log2 =x
x =log(n+1/2)

=> no of leaves = (n+1)/2 (which is 2^(log(n+1/2))
```

Answer (score 2):

A good intuition for this is to think about this inductively. For the n = 0 case, there aren't any leaves, and for the n = 1 case the root is the only leaf. For each added node after that, it either (1) adds a child to a node that was previously a leaf and now has one child, not changing the number of leaf nodes, or (2) adds a child to a node that already has one child, increasing the number of leaves by one. Using induction, you can formalize this to prove that the number of leaves in a binary heap is ⌈n / 2⌉.

Comment: I dont understand. Because I think when N is 3( 3 nodes), it has one root and two leaves. Isn't it?

Comment: Yep! And ceil(3/2) = 2.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we have `n` nodes so

```
0-level
1-level
...
d-level                          // Total 2^d nodes at this level. #ofLeafNodes at this level depends on how many nodes are there at below level. 
last-level-containing-X-nodes    // All leaf nodes
```

Leaf nodes can come only from last two levels.

Last level have `x` leaf nodes. 
While second last level would have total 2^d nodes and ⌈x / 2⌉ leaf nodes.

So, in total leaf nodes =

```
= (Leaf nodes at bottom-most level) + (Leaf nodes at second bottom-most level) 
= (x + (2^d - ⌈x / 2⌉))                 //Equation 1
```

---

Total nodes in the binary heap tree=>

```
n       = (2^(d + 1) - 1) + x
2*(2^d) = n-x+1
2^d     = (n-x+1)/2
```

Now substitute `2^d` in above eq#1,

```
(x + (2^d - ⌈x / 2⌉))
=(x + (n-x+1)/2 - ⌈x / 2⌉)
= n/2 + x/2 + 1/2 - ⌈x / 2⌉
```

---

For even `n`, `x` will be odd:

```
= n/2 + x/2 + 1/2 - (x/2 + 1/2)
= n/2 + x/2 + 1/2 - x/2 - 1/2
= n/2
= ⌈n / 2⌉        /*Since n is even*/
```

For odd `n`, `x` will be even:

```
= n/2 + x/2 + 1/2 - (x/2 + 1/2)
= n/2 + x/2 + 1/2 - x/2
= n/2 + 1/2 
= ⌈n / 2⌉
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, we need to find the last internal node and the first leaf node of the heap.

From the heap property, we know that a node with index i,

```
Parent[i] = ceil(i/2)
Left[i]   = 2i
Right[i]  = 2i+1
```

Assume the last internal node is at floor(n/2), and first leaf node is at floor(n/2)+1.

```
Right[floor(n/2)]
=   2(floor(n/2)) + 1
<=  2 * (n-(2-1))/2 + 1
=   2 * (n-1)/2 + 1
=   n
```

From Right[ floor(n/2) ] <= n, we know that floor(n/2) will have a right child in bound of the heap, thus, it is the last internal nodes. Also, all nodes before floor(n/2) will be internal nodes that have a right child in bound of the heap. Then, we know that internal nodes are indexed by 1, 2, 3, 4, ... floor(n/2), which means the index of last internal is number of internal nodes in the heap.

```
Left[floor(n/2) + 1]
=   2 * (floor(n/2) + 1)
>   2 * (n/2 - 1 + 1)
=   2 * n/2
=   n
```

From Left[ floor(n/2)+1] <= n, we know that floor(n/2)+1 will have a left child out of bound of the heap, thus, it is the first leaf node. Also, all nodes after floor(n/2)+1 will have a left child out of bound of the heap. Then, we know that nodes after floor(n/2) (last internal node), in the heap will not have child nodes, so they are all leaves that are indexed by floor(n/2)+1, floor(n/2)+2, floor(n/2)+3, ... n.

Thus, from above we know that:

```
number of leaves = element of heap - number of internal nodes
                 = n - floor(n/2)
                 = ceil(n/2)
```